# How to use phpunit in my application that has made by ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, symfony4, phpunit

I've looked for a while in google How to use PHPUnit to test my application but I couldn't find anything useful. My application has been developing by Symfony4 as backend and ReactJs as frontend.

Here is my problem :

```
   $Client  = static::createClient();
   $Crawler = $Client->request('GET', '/admin/login');
```

I expected the $Crawler value contains virtual dom but it only contains the container div element :

```
<div id="login"></div>
```

but in fact, after ReactJs rendering, it should be like this :

```
<div id="login" data-error="" data-username="" data-token="8HjNpXOlKGvcgPUJ74mGedyQkeWZkNvOFCreMzTBTN8"><div class="Login-root-1"><div class="MuiGrid-container-14 MuiGrid-direction-xs-row-reverse-19 MuiGrid-align-items-xs-center-22 MuiGrid-justify-xs-center-31">.....
```

and here is the test function :

```
    public function testLogin() {

    $Client = static::createClient();
    $Client->request('GET', '/admin/login');
    $Crawler = $Client->getCrawler();
    $Form    = $Crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
    ........
}
```

What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Since React get initialized asynchronously after the page get loaded you should wait until your React elements can be found in the DOM.

As the DomCrawler is not really designed for testing frontend-heavy async applications, I would recommend to distinguish your tests:

- Check on the backend with PHPUnit and DomCrawler that the specific get loaded properly (for example it returns 200 status code)
- Check the frontend application itself with [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and/or [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme)